# Fastest way to check if a string exists in a large number of files

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I am currently iterating over somewhere between 7000 and 10000 text definitions varying in size between 0 and 5000 characters and I want to check whether a particular string exists in any of them. I want to do this for somewhere in the region of 5000 different string definitions.

In most cases I just want to to know an exact case-insensitive match however sometimes a regex is required to be more specific. I was wondering though whether it would be quicker to use another "search" technique when the regex isn't required.

A slimmed version of the code looks something like this.

```
foreach (string find in stringsiWantToFind)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(find, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (String s in listOfText)
        if (rx.IsMatch(s))
            find.FoundIn(s);
}
```

I've read around a bit to see whether I'm missing anything obvious. There are a number of suggestions for using Compliled regexs however I can't see that is helpful given the "dynamic" nature of the regex.

I also read an interesting [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/string_optimizations.aspx?msg=3328426) on CodeProject so I'm just about to look at using the "FastIndexOf" to see how it compares in performance.

I just wondered if anybody had any advice for this kind of problem and how performance can potentially be optimized?

Thanks

Comment: The "compiled" version will be used for each comparison.  If you have 10,000 files (not clear from your question) it will be compiled one and re-used 10K times rather than interpreted 10K times.

Really suggest you leave text indexing to a package you purchase.

Comment: How can it be compiled if the search term isn't know until run time?

Comment: Using a Regex is a good idea here because the .Net implementation will use a Boyer-Moore search algorithm for trivial cases that will be much faster than IndexOf().

Comment: what is the format of the input files? plain-text? csv? xml? This knowledge could open up your options.

Comment: Well all definitions have been read in to a string variable. Some are XML but most just plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Make one regular expression which contains all the strings you want to match then loop over the files with that regex. The  `new Regex` parameter is prob wrong, my knowledge of .net regex patterns is not the best. Also i've left out a few `using` to make it more readable here. You could make the `Regex` compiled if this improves things.

```
Regex rx = new Regex("string1|string2|string3|string5|string-etc", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
  var fs = new FileStream(fileName.ToString(), FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);    
  var sr = new StreamReader(fs);    
  var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

  string readFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
  MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(readFile );

  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Was considering whether that was a good idea so will give it a go.

Comment: Just done a quick test and it would seem there is no performance improvement with the above method.

Comment: the example appears to have already loaded the files into memory before we get to the example code, my version is loading them in the loop, have you taken this into account?

Comment: I can't see how it makes any difference when the texts are loaded, as it is the regex that is doing all the work and taking all the time.

Comment: Sorry i found the original question a little confusing, I thought you were searching 7000 to 10000 files for your text? My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a file indexing service like [MS Indexing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689718%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [Google Desktop Search](http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/docs/searchapi.html).  Those APIs will allow you to search the indexes of your files rather than the files themselves and are extremely fast.

Comment: What defines the list of Texts is defined from a number of different sources. So for example in some cases it is obtained from file and in others from a field in a database.

Comment: Could you use the indexing service in conjunction with a full-text SQL query then?

Comment: I guess I could do yeah. The code currently runs in about 15 minutes so in principle I wasn't looking to change the structure of it. I was mainly looking for a small chage to the existing structure that could yield a number of minutes performance improvement.

Answer (score -1):

One trick that came to my mind was:

Concatenate the strings into 1 big one, have the regex work on global level. That would yield you results of a ´string found xx times´ using 1 regex instead of looping over your list.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I possibly should have been more specific in my example(I will change it). I need to know which "source" the text was found in.